# what is alignment css style for table layout?

Tags: css

I have a table in html. I prefer to layout the table centered. What is the css style for this layout? And any online css tools to interactively see the style change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <!-- contents -->
  </table>
</div>
```

You can use this CSS:

```
div{
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
div table{
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
}
```

Most browsers will already work if you apply `margin: 0 auto` to the `table`.

However, the `text-align` CSS makes it work for pickier browsers. Specifically, `text-align: center` will center the `table`, but since it would have a side effect of also centering each cell's contents, you need to apply `text-align: left` to the table to reset that property.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, it's the [text-align](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_text-align.asp) property. Or do you mean center the table in the html page?